# Исключения в методе класса с++

Tags: c++, исключения, try-catch

Почему в методе `divisionNum` после оператора `throw` работа `try`-блока не останавливается и не переходит к выполнению кода `catch`-блока, а спокойно проходит к строке `cout << num1 / num2` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class P
{
public:
    int num1,
        num2;

    P(int _num1, int _num2)
    {
        num1 = _num1;
        num2 = _num2;
    }

    void sumNum()
    {
        cout << num1 + num2 << endl;
    }

    void divisionNum()
    {
        if (num2 == 0)
        {
            throw "PPPPP";
        }
        cout << num1 / num2;
    }

    ~P()
    {}
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    P obj2(10, 0);

    try
    {
        obj2.divisionNum();
    }
    catch (string s)
    {
        cout << s << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Если напишете так, то будет отлавливаться `throw string("PPPPP");`, т.е. неявного приведения типов не происходит (от `char*` к `std::string`). А вообще, это плохая практика кидать исключение классом, который сам может его сгенерировать (я про `std::string`), используйте соответствующие классы, например, `std::exception`.

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что происходит выполнение `cout << num1 / num2;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить вместо ***string s***      ***...***.

```
catch (...)
```

Из МСДН...

> Выражение throw вызывает исключение, т.е. создает его. Блок кода после
>   предложения catch является обработчиком исключения.Это обработчик,
>   который перехватывает исключение, вызываемое, ЕСЛИ ТИПЫ В ВЫРАЖЕНИЯХ
>   throw и catch СОВМЕСТИМЫ.

По хорошему, нужно было бы, чтобы таким типом являлся производный класс от класса exception. Так как Вы не использовали такой тип, а словить исключение все-таки нужно, то читаем тот же МСДН далее.

> Если оператор catch задает многоточие (...) вместо типа, блок catch
>   обрабатывает ВСЕ ТИПЫ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЙ.

**Обновление**

Из МСДН (что это такое объяснять, думаю, не нужно) *Выражение throw вызывает исключение, т.е. создает его. Блок кода после предложения catch является обработчиком исключения.Это обработчик, который перехватывает исключение, вызываемое, ЕСЛИ ТИПЫ В ВЫРАЖЕНИЯХ throw и catch СОВМЕСТИМЫ.*

По хорошему, нужно было бы, чтобы таким типом являлся производный класс от класса exception. Так как Вы не использовали такой тип, а словить исключение все-таки нужно, то читаем тот же МСДН далее. *Если оператор catch задает многоточие (...) вместо типа, блок catch обрабатывает ВСЕ ТИПЫ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЙ.*

Так что отвечая на Ваш вопрос о том, является ли костылем **(...)** - в данном конкретном случае не является.

Comment: Спасибо, так все работает. Не подскажите почему "Просто поменял string s на char *s" - костыль, а catch (...) нет? И главная "непонятка" на данный момент - "И используйте в throw числительные.", почему throw  нельзя оставить пустым, если после него все равно можно написать рандомное число, которое далее не используется?

Comment: @Aselmo Что же касается числительных, то взгляните на [этот код](http://ideone.com/6ju26q) и результат его работы. Этот пример показывает как можно использовать числительные для определения того, что вызвало исключение. Ваш же пример, я даже не уверен, что везде скомпилируется.

Comment: @Aselmo В качестве большого спасибо используется на данном ресурсе голосование за ответ и/или, если ответ устраивает - отмечается галочкой. Если ответ не полный, то можно сообщить об этом и топикастер его с удовольствием дополнит. Также можно голосовать и за комментарии.

Comment: Далеко не лучшее решение. Это скорее ultima ratio, когда надо просто аккуратно завершить программу, но так вы НЕ ПОЛУЧИТЕ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ о том, что же, собственно, произошло. `catch(...)` - это решение "от отчаяния" :)

Comment: @Harry А Вы комментарии прямо перед своим прочитали? :) Не? Не нужно? :) Хотя это, наверное, и часть моей вины, что не перенес всю инфу из комментариев в ответ...

Answer (score 5):

Позвольте дать пару советов.
Для начала - генерировать исключения лучше по значению (не как указатель), а перехватывать - как ссылку. Дополнительным бонусом будет то, что

```
catch(const base&)
```

будет перехватывать как исключение `base`, так и производные от него. Отсюда, кстати, еще один совет - сначала пишите `catch` для производных исключений, а потом для базовых, ну, а последним `catch(...)`.

Во-вторых, я бы советовал использовать в качестве базового исключение `std::exception`, ну, а использовать свои производные, или воспользоваться готовой иерархией типа `logic_error`, `domain_error` и иже с ними - это вопрос, на который я пока не видел убедительного однозначного ответа.

Но использовать всяческие встроенные типы - как `int`, `char*` и т.п. - лучше не надо. Не то что это запрещено, но потом самому продраться сквозь свои же исключения будет сложновато...

Ну, у себя вы ошибку уже обнаружили - в `catch` нет неявного приведения типов...

И еще - у вас в первоначальной версии на самом деле строка деления НЕ выполняется, вы зря это написали; скорее всего, вы просто получаете аварийное завершение программы - из-за **неперехваченного** исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался, если вдруг кому будет нужно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class P
{
public:
int num1,
    num2;

P(int _num1, int _num2)
{
    num1 = _num1;
    num2 = _num2;
}

void sumNum()
{
    cout << num1 + num2 << endl;
}

void divisionNum()
{
    if (num2 == 0)
    {
        throw "PPP";
    }
    cout << num1 / num2;
}

~P()
{}
};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
P obj2(10, 0);

try
{
    obj2.divisionNum();
}
catch (char *s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

Просто поменял string s на char *s

Comment: Боюсь, что Ваше решение - есть костыль и мало кому понадобится.

Answer (score 0):

> Просто поменял string s на char *s
>
> Боюсь, что Ваше решение - есть костыль и мало кому понадобится. – Max ZS 11 мар '16 в 19:20

Боюсь Вы не знаете основ, в которых строка вида "blablabla" имеет тип char*, и исключение вполне корректно его отлавливает. Хотите отловить string - пишите:

```
string s = "blablabla";
throw s;
```

или что-то вроде

```
throw string("blablabla");
```